# Display NotifyOSD Notifcations in Conky?

Tags: notify-osd, conky

I want to display the latest NotifyOSD notification in conky, I can display the entire file with

${execi 30 cat ~/.cache/notify-osd.log}

But is it possible to show only the last line of the file? and get it to periodically check the log for changes to the last line?

Comment: Please answer the question, don't put your solution in the question.

Answer (score 3):

As you pointed out:

> I sorted the problem by using this
>
> `${execi 30 cat
>   ~/.cache/notify-osd.log| tail -4}`
>
> which works perfectly
>
> ([source](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=72532))